# OCI8 installation issue in Centos 7

Tags: php, apache-2.4, oracle

I installed PHP 5.6 and Apache 2.4, and oci8 module on my fresh Centos 7 system.

The oci8 module is working on terminal, but it's not working in Apache and not showing in phpinfo.

- I tried to disable SELinux
- I tried to setup environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH
- I tried to reinstall all of them again

All of them don't work.

I tried to look at the apache log:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pdo_oci.so' - libclntsh.so.12.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

Please help and thank you in advance!

Comment: Where did you setup `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? That has to go into `/etc/sysconfig/httpd`.

Comment: I just added LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib in /etc/sysconfig/httpd and restarted apache, but it doesn't work

Comment: And where did you add the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`? Can you verify that `/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pdo_oci.so` is there and also try `ldd /usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/pdo_oci.so` to see if there are more libraries missing.

Comment: I added  LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib  to /etc/sysconfig/httpd file. Is it right?

Comment: That should be the place to add this. You can verify it with `strings /proc/$(pidof -s httpd)/environ`. Also verify that the needed files are in place.

Comment: I run the command, but it didn't show the variable I added.

Answer (score 1):

I found that has to add environment variable in
 /usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service
by adding 
Environment=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/oracle/12.2/client64/lib/:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH